# Dynamic object casting in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, dynamic-data

I want to create a generic component in flex.
This component deals with different ArrayCollections dynamically (I want it in that way).
So I thought to pass the arrayCollection and the type of that arrayCollection as arguments to the component.

Like,

```
var list:ArrayCollection<ClassA>;
init_Comp(list, "ClassA");
```

If it is possible, I can read it like this,

```
var newDynamicInstatnce: typeOf("ClassA") = list.getItemAt(0) as typeOf("ClassA");
```

Finally I have a Dynamic Instance type of that I pass.

Is this possible in Flex or Is there a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: The code you provided won't work in Flex/ActionScript, as you dont declare the type of the ArrayCollection in actionscript ArrayCollection<type>. But what i would do in your scenario is using if statements to check for the class type, and then instantiate a new variable like so:
`if(list.getItemAt(0) is ClassA) {
var newDynamicInstance:ClassA = list.getItemAt(0) as ClassA; }`

Comment: Why does your generic component needs to know about a speficic type?

Answer (score 0):

1. Sounds interesting. You could pass type as constructor argument.

   new TypedCollection(ClassA)

   addTypedItem(item) {
      if (item is checkType) {
2. Comprehensive solution is to add changes to Flex SDK (java code) to support generics on compile level.

But I think this will be thankless work. From whom you want to be type protected? From yourself?